# Setting up PHP nested variable

Tags: php

I have the following code that works:

```
$apple_color = "red";
$pear_color = "green";
$banana_color = "yellow";
$grape_color = "purple";

foreach(array("apple","pear","banana","grape") as $idx=>$fname) {
    $var = "${fname}_color";
    echo "$var = ${$var}<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to shorten the code by eliminating the $var variable to something like this:

```
foreach(array("apple","pear","banana","grape") as $idx=>$fname) {
    echo "${fname}_color = ${${fname}_color}<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

The "${${fname}_color" returns an PHP error that says "syntax error, unexpected '_color' (T_STRING)"

PHP Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/wrfp-yqkx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Use `${'string'}` construction

```
foreach(["apple","pear","banana","grape"] as $fname) {
    echo "{$fname}_color = ".${$fname.'_color'}."<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a separate variable for each color, store the colors in an array indexed by the fruit name. This way you can avoid the mess of using variable variables.

```
$colors = [
    'apple' => 'red',
    'pear' => 'green',
    'banana' => 'yellow',
    'grape' => 'purple'
];

foreach (["apple","pear","banana","grape"] as $fname) {
    echo "{$fname}_color = $colors[$fname]<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Your idea works, however, in my situation, I have no control over the initial variable names that is passed into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting to simplify your life:

```
echo sprintf('$%s_color = %s<br>' . PHP_EOL, $fname, ${$fname . '_color'});
```